# Extracting Emails and Phone numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

im using google sheets and want to extract emails and phone numbers. Lets assume i have a text in one cell:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem b.hoang@hotmail.de ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. +49 176 420 59178 At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

How would you proceed to get the email and phone details?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Have you tried REGEXEXTRACT? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

For email, you can try

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(your text,"[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+")
```

[image]

For phone number, try

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\+[0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+")
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need any other help?